# Numerical differentiation (approximation with three supporting points )

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, numerical-methods

Given the supporting points $x-2h,x-h,x+2h$. Determine the difference quotient Du(x) in the form

$$Du(x)=au(x-2h)+bu(x-h)+cu(x+2h)$$

for the numerical approximation of $u'(x)$ of order $2$. What are the values $a,b,c?$

I tried to get same equation with the taylor expansion and I tried to connect that equation together to get the desired form. But that didnt help me :(

Can someone help me?

Comment: What are your Taylor expansions? Note that you can also get this by computing the interpolating polynomial.

Comment: Write down the three Taylor series required, multiply them respectively by $a,b$ and $c$ then write a system of three equations of these three unknowns in a way to cancel out the $u(x)$'s and $u''(x)$'s but keep the $u'(x)$'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you're looking for is $u'(x)$

$$a*u(x-2h)=a*u(x)-a*u'(x)*(2h)+ a*u''(x)*(2h)^2+...$$
$$b*u(x-h)=b*u(x)-b*u'(x)*(h)+ b*u''(x)*(h)^2+...$$
$$c*u(x+2h)=c*u(x)+c*u'(x)*(2h)+ c*u''(x)*(2h)^2+...$$

Hence:

$$a+b+c=0$$
$$-2a-b+2c=1$$ (or any non zero value other than $1$ but be careful later)
$$4a+b+4c=0$$

Solve for $a,b$and $c$ and you're done.

> $a=-1/4,b=0,c=1/4$

Comment: This is the standard method when looking for a differentiation or integration of a particular form and degree